# List all DOM events of a page loaded in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs

I would like to log all events that are bind in JS and html. My current solution, it does not log anything, what am I doing wrong, or is there a better way on capturing events and saving its callbacks?

```js
'use strict';
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
};

page.open('url', function (status) {
    var _count = function() {
        return page.evaluate(function() {
            var htmlAddEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;
            HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function(name, cb) {
                console.log('1', name);
                this.boundEvents || (this.boundEvents = {});
                (this.boundEvents[name] || (this.boundEvents[name] = [])).push(cb);
                return htmlAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            var elementAddEventListener = Element.prototype.addEventListener;
            Element.prototype.addEventListener = function(name, cb) {
                console.log('1', name);
                this.boundEvents || (this.boundEvents = {});
                (this.boundEvents[name] || (this.boundEvents[name] = [])).push(cb);
                return elementAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            var documentAddEventListener = Document.prototype.addEventListener;
            Document.prototype.addEventListener = function(name, cb) {
                console.log('2', name);
                this.boundEvents || (this.boundEvents = {});
                (this.boundEvents[name] || (this.boundEvents[name] = [])).push(cb);
                return documentAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            var windowAddEventListener = window.addEventListener;
            window.addEventListener = function(name, cb) {
                console.log('3', name);
                this.boundEvents || (this.boundEvents = {});
                (this.boundEvents[name] || (this.boundEvents[name] = [])).push(cb);
                return windowAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
            }

            var elementDispatchEvent = Element.prototype.dispatchEvent;
            Element.prototype.dispatchEvent = function(name, cb) {
                console.log('1a', name);
                return elementDispatchEvent.apply(this, arguments);
            }
        });
    }
    _count();

});
```

Comment: it looks like it is the order. when I trigger an event at the end of evalute I get it logged .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the various `addEventListener` functions in the built-in object prototypes *after* the page has loaded. The `page.open` callback is called most of the time after all immediate page JavaScript has run. If the page you're loading doesn't make use of dynamic requests, nothing's going be shown.

You should call `_count` from an event handler that runs *before* the page JavaScript is executed. Examples are [`page.onInitialized`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-initialized.html), `page.onLoadStarted`, `page.onNavigationRequested` and `page.onUrlChanged`. Make sure that you're not calling it more than once.